# Codeigniter 4 dropzone upload after redirect url

Tags: codeigniter, dropzone

I am uploading files with Codeigniter 4. I want the page to refresh after loading but my code is not working. Here is the controller I use.
At the bottom I have the code for the redirect but this code is not working.

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\Hizmetmodels;
use App\Models\Dosyamodels;

class Dosyacontroller extends BaseController

{
    protected $helpers = ['form' ,'url'];
    protected $Dosyamodels;

    public function index($sap = null)
    
    {
        
        $Hizmetmodels= new Hizmetmodels();
        $data['hizmetsat'] = $Hizmetmodels->where('sap', $sap)->first();

        $Dosyamodels= new Dosyamodels();
        $where = "sap='$sap'";
        $data['dosya'] = $Dosyamodels->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->where($where)->findAll();  
        
        return view('Admin/Dosyalar/index', $data);

    }
    public function form()
    {
        $sap = $this->request->getPost('sap');
        $Dosyamodels= new Dosyamodels();
        helper(['text','inflector']);
        $file = $this->request->getFile('file');
        $size = $file->getSize();
        $kilobytes = $file->getSizeByUnit('kb');
        $path = 'public/uploads';
        $name = convert_accented_characters(underscore($file->getName()));
        $newname = "$sap-$name";
        $file->move(ROOTPATH . $path, $newname);
        $ext = $file->getClientExtension();

        $data = [
            'adi' => $newname,
            'yol' => $path . '/' . $name,
            'sap' => $sap,
            'boyut' => $kilobytes,
            'uzt' => $ext,

        ];

        $save = $Dosyamodels->insert($data);
        return redirect()->to('/Dosyalar/index/'. $sap)->with('success', 'Tebrikler! <br> Dosyalar başarı ile yüklendi.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With dropzone the document is uploaded to the correct folder. saved to the database. no problems so far. the only problem is i can't refresh the page no matter what i do after it loads.here is my java script code:

```
$(function() {
Dropzone.options.dropzoneform = {
paramName: 'file',
maxFilesize: 2, // MB
maxFiles: 5,
init: function () {
    this.on('queuecomplete', function (file) {
        location.reload();
    });
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change
`this.on('queuecomplete', function (file) { location.reload(); });` to `this.on('success', function (file, responseText) { location.reload(); });`